# PUT http request 403 error in amazon s3 image upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am following an amazon s3 image upload tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) . Everything seems fine. My signed url responses return 200 status code . However, the last upload function is throwing an 403 status code .

```
function upload_file(file, signed_request, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("preview").src = url;
            document.getElementById("avatar_url").value = url;
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert("Could not upload file.");
    };
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

The error is thrown at the request here

```
    xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
```

I checked my networked and see a successful Response of type OPTIONS delivered with a 200 status code. However, the last resquest of type PUT with the same header and properties failed.

My keys are represented in my sign_s3 python function below

```
@app.route('/sign_s3/')
def sign_s3():
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY'  # string
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY' #string
    S3_BUCKET = 'MY_S3_BUCKET' # string
    object_name = urllib.quote_plus(request.args.get('file_name'))
    mime_type = request.args.get('file_type')

    expires = int(time.time()+60*60*24)
    amz_headers = "x-amz-acl:public-read"

    string_to_sign = "PUT\n\n%s\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s" % (mime_type, expires, amz_headers, S3_BUCKET, object_name)
   print "%s" %string_to_sign
   signature = base64.encodestring(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_KEY.encode(), string_to_sign.encode('utf8'), sha1).digest())
   signature = urllib.quote_plus(signature.strip())

   url = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, object_name)

   content = json.dumps({
    'signed_request': '%s?AWSAccessKeyId=%s&Expires=%s&Signature=%s' % (url, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, expires, signature),
    'url': url,
    })
    return content
```

Please where do i got wrong ? I am running my flask server on a localhost with an address http://127.0.0.1:8080/. Please where do i go wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming your access and secret keys are correct - you need to show the full source of how you generate the signature. Do you generate an HMAC during your signed request?

Comment: @birryree i have updated my code. Please see above . Thanks

Comment: 403 with what in the body?

Comment: the OPTIONS with a 200 response is a preflight request

Comment: a dump of the traffic would definitely answer the questions, but at this point: you either don't have permissions, the way you compute the signature is wrong or the time on the box that does this is not UTC (leading to a wrong signature)

Comment: @thext 403 (Forbidden). In the console, it wrote this " PUT .." Put with my request signed url. Then 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: @thext how do i generate the dump of the traffic pls?

Comment: in the browser using developer tools (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) or using a specialized proxy like Charles (https://www.charlesproxy.com)

Answer (score 1):

Note the format, again:

```
StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
Content-MD5 + "\n" +
Content-Type + "\n" +
Expires + "\n" +
CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
CanonicalizedResource;
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth

The `CanonicalizedResource` should be...

```
/bucket/object_name
```

...but your code...

```
string_to_sign = "PUT\n\n%s\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s" % (mime_type, expires, amz_headers, S3_BUCKET, object_name)
```

...is going to create this, instead:

```
bucket
object_name
```

...so it looks like your format string actually needs to be...

```
"PUT\n\n%s\n%d\n%s\n/%s/%s"
```

Comment: H @Michael. Thanks for the correction. IT still throws the same forbiddden 403 status code error. Its confusing .

Comment: The `403` response should include a response body that gives you some information about what went wrong with your signing process, if the signing process is at fault.  If the apparent bug I've identified in this answer is not the only issue, then you will need to capture that response.

Comment: However... do make sure the `AWSAccessKeyId` corresponds with a user that has been granted the `s3:PutObject` **and** `s3:PutObjectAcl` permissions.

Comment: It does have the error `request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`. I cofirm the keyid and the secret key are all correct , yet it said the calculated signature does not match. The error is clear . But the reason is not.